# I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what <.<

Tags: php

My function is

```
 function getReg($id) {
    return file_get_contents('http://arcbots.com/userinfo.php?id='.$id);
  }
```

My php for the echo is

```
<?php
    function display()
    {
        echo getReg('$_POST["search"]');
    }
    if(isset($_POST["search"]))
    {
       display();
    } 
    ?>
```

and my form code is

```
<center><form method="post" />
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="submit">
</form></center>
```

I know I'm doing something very wrong. If the code was to work when I search "1111211137" it should return "LeJordannn" Its returning "Danjr4149000099" meaning I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `getReg($_POST["search"]);`

Comment: You're closing the form tag right away. I don't know if it changes anything.

Comment: Please don't use the `<center>` tag. It was deprecated during the Clinton administration and shouldn't be used.

Comment: You should edit the question title, for it is not clear what's the question about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes in PHP tell PHP not to parse for those variables, so it assumes everything passed to getReg is a literal. Redo your function like this:

```
<?php
    function display()
    {
        echo getReg($_POST['search']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST["search"]))
    {
       display();
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
    function display($term)
    {
        echo getReg($term);
    }
    if(isset($_POST["search"]))
    {
       display($_POST["search"]);
    } 
    ?>
```

do it this way and your function can be reused with different values